# Jhipster Okta Ionic

Tags: spring, ionic-framework, spring-security, jhipster, okta

I'm trying to make a connection through Okta with my jhipster ionic app.

Everything works fine with the angular web part but with my ionic app after clicking on connect, it send me back to the welcome page with an Unauthorized (401) error in the console.

As if I had only reloaded the page

My Okta config :

[image]

Comment: The current version of Ionic JHipster (v3.3.0) doesn't support authorization code flow, only implicit flow. See https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/01/30/jhipster-ionic-with-oidc-authentication. v4.0 will support it, as shown in this screencast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBAUKQGNx5Y. I don't have a timeline for its release, but hopefully within the next six weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the video link I'll try it ! But when i'm connected in front part how to check that the user is really connected in the backend (spring boot) part ?

Comment: The JHipster Ionic module doesn't support Ionic 4 yet, so it's not quite possible unless you want to code it up yourself.